# R: How to change numeric values in a list of dataframes to a character based on where they are in relation to specific quantitative thresholds?

Tags: r

I have list of dataframes each of which contains numerical values

```
#DummyData
df1 = data.frame(x = rnorm(11), y = rnorm(11))
df2 = data.frame(x = rnorm(11), y = rnorm(11))
df3 = data.frame(x = rnorm(11), y = rnorm(11))
df_list = mget(ls(pattern = "df[1-3]"))
```

I want to recode the numerical values based on their relation to +/-10% around the mean. Specifically I want to change values greater than 10 percent higher than the mean to "High", values within 10% of the mean to "Medium", and values more than 10% lower than the mean to "low".

My strategy to do this has been to use a function made of multiple ifelse statements, and then use lapply to apply it to the list

```
myfunction <- function(x) {C <-mean(x)
ifelse(x > 1.1*C, "High", x) 
ifelse(x < 0.9*C, "Low", "Medium")
}

df_list <- lapply(df_list, myfunction)
```

When i do this, I get only Low and Medium in df_list, no High.  If i comment out the second ifelse statement, i get High assigned. How can i change my function to fix this problem? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try chaining together both `ifelse()` calls:

```
myfunction <- function(x) {
    C <- mean(x)
    ifelse(x > 1.1*C, "High", ifelse(x < 0.9*C, "Low", "Medium")) 
}
```

Your current logic means that *both* `ifelse()` will be evaluated even if the first one fires true for High.  But if a value be High, then you don't want another assignment to happen.